# [eclipse pde]How to catch the event that a launch is terminated?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, launch

I'm writing a eclipse plugin.

I want to do sth. when a launch is terminated, where do I add the code?

I have already wrote a class that extends JavaLaunchDelegate.