# Blocking version of AtomicReference<T> - Wait for an Eclipse Launch to terminate

Tags: java, concurrency, eclipse-plugin, launching

I am looking for a blocking version of `AtomicReference` to avoid such active waiting:

```
AtomicReference<Object> ref = new AtomicReference<Object>();
// execute some code in a different thread and set the reference
Object o;
while ((o = ref.get()) == null);
// continue execution
```

Java provides a `Future` interface, which blocks in `get()` method. But I cannot use that part of `concurrent` package because the reference should be set by a framework where the usage of a simple listener is expected.

To be more precise I work with the launching framework in Eclipse. I fire a maven launch via `org.eclipse.m2e.actions.ExecutePomAction` but I don't have a directly access to its process because it's [hidden deeply in JDT](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.debug.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.launching/launching/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/launching/StandardVMRunner.java#n425). That's why I'm using Eclipse's launch manager for that purpose:

```
final ILaunchManager launchMan = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
launchMan.addLaunchListener(new ILaunchListener() {
    public void launchRemoved(ILaunch launch) {
        ILaunchConfiguration conf = launch.getLaunchConfiguration();
        if (("Executing install in "+proj.getLocation().toOSString().replace('\\', '-')).equals(conf.getName()))
        {
            IProcess[] processes = launch.getProcesses();
            if (processes.length == 1)
                procRef.set(processes[0]);
        }
        launchMan.removeLaunchListener(this);
    }
});
```

I think there is no other way to use active waiting afterwards, because IProcess provides no possibility to listen on its termination. Kinda like this:

```
BusyIndicator.showWhile(Display.getCurrent(), new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (!proc.isTerminated())
            Thread.sleep(500);
    }
});
```

This question has basically something common with [[eclipse pde]How to catch the event that a launch is terminated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10185794/1851290) but it's quite old and I provided here more information on my investigations.

Comment: "should be set by a framework where the usage of a simple listener is expected" can you elaborate on that? What is your definition of a "simple listener"?

Comment: Edited the question to add more details on my riddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DebugPlugin.getDefault().addDebugEventFilter(filter)` to set up an `IDebugEventFilter` class.

This is given all the debug / run events include the `DebugEvent.TERMINATE` event when a launch terminates.

Answer (score 1):

I also found another way to do it with a launch manager. I just had to use another listener interface:

```
final ILaunchManager launchMan = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
launchMan.addLaunchListener(new ILaunchesListener2()
{
    public void launchesTerminated(ILaunch[] launches)
    {
        for (ILaunch launch : launches) {
            ILaunchConfiguration conf = launch.getLaunchConfiguration();
            if (("Executing install in "+proj.getLocation().toOSString().replace('\\', '-')).equals(conf.getName()))
            {
                //my maven launch is terminated!
            }
        }
    }
});
```